# How to add text from array into an text label in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, textlabel, detailtextlabel

I have a storyboard with two labels in a `UITableViewCell`.

title and price.

In my `ViewController.m` I have an array with data(from a url in JSON). I get all I need BUT when I want to add this data into the label, I tried something like this:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
  UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  // Get the location to be shown
  Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
  NSString *baseUrl = @"address/to/image";
  NSString *urlString = [baseUrl stringByAppendingString:item.thumbnail];
  NSURL *urla = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urla];
  UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

  myCell.imageView.image = image;

  myCell.detailTextLabel.text = item.elementid; // "No visible @interface for 'Location' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:' 
  myCell.textLabel.text = item.element;         //"No visible @interface for 'Location' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'

  return myCell;
  }

It does not work and I don't know why. I didn't receive any error message. Can anyone help me?

Comment: in your CellforRowAtIndexPath: Method you can set myCell.detailTextLabel.text = [item.elementid objectAtindex:IndexPath.row];

Comment: Define "does not work".  And what have you done to debug?  Have you NSLogged `item` at the point you're referencing it?

Comment: "does not work" means that i can't see the data from array in my LABEL fields :(

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Array text in the label at the indexPath.row

```
myCell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
myCell.textLabel.text = [item objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Or a more modern approach would be myCell.detailTextLabel.text = item[indexPath.row];

Comment: thx very much!! i got an error ... "No visible @interface for 'Location' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:' ... i know i know ... but i have to say i started in objective-c :)

Comment: @user3518279 : Make sure you are using `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`